# Constructing Context Free Grammar with 3 terminal symbols, with two dependent pairs

Tags: computability, context-free, formal-grammars, pushdown-automata

I am new to Context Free Grammars and am having trouble wrapping my head around how to approach writing a CFG for the following language:

```
L = {a^n b^m+n c^m | n>=0, m>=1}
```

I have a basic understanding of how this should work, but the examples we went over in class usually only had either 2 symbols dependent on each other, or completely independent. Having to determine the number of b's based on the number of a's + c's is throwing me for a loop.

I am thinking this will involve the union of several grammars.

```
s1 - no a's, equal b'c and c's 
s2 - equal a's and c's, 2x b's
s3 - more a's than c's
s4 - more c's than a's
```

I believe I know how to approach the first two, but the second two I am a bit fuzzy on how to proceed.

Comment: hint: think about {a^n b^m+n c^m | n>=0, m>=1} and how it relates to the two following languages {a^n b^n| n>=0 }, {b^m c^m | m>=1}

Comment: hint2: $m+n=n+m$. Trivial, yet useful here.

Comment: @chi I've gotten it to: S -> S1 | S2, S1 -> aAb | epsilon, A -> aAb | epsilon,  S2 -> bCc | epsilon, C -> bCc | epsilon, however, I am still having expected strings in the language fail a brute force parser. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Ah, I think I found my mistake. S - > S1 | S2 | S1S2